# Django 2.2 reverse lookup NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, html, django

I am porting an old project from an older version of django to django 2.2 and python 3.6.8. I am running into an issue resolving a page that includes a reverse lookup link and getting this error

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'views.users_staff' not found. 'views.users_staff' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

It looks to me like it can't find the view using the reverse url I have in my urls.py file but I can't figure out how it needs to be written.

Here is what I have right now.

**html template**:

```
{% if user.isManager %}
            <tr>
                <td class="field">staff list</td>
                <td class="value"><a href="{% url 'views.users_staff' env user.hid %}">Link</a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field">org chart</td>
                <td class="value"><a href="{% url 'views.users_staff' env user.hid %}?org=1">Link</a>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
```

This page specifically does an LDAP call for a user and if the user is a manager it includes these links on the page to their direct reports.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    # path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', views.static.serve, {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.DJANGO_PROJECT_ROOT, 'user_search/media')}),
    # re_path(r'^$', views.index, name=index),
    re_path(r'^user/$', views.users_default, name='users_default'),
    re_path(r'^user/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/$', views.users,
         name='users'),
    re_path(r'^user/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/(?P<hid>[0-9]+)/$',
         views.users_staff, name='users_staff')**,
    re_path(r'^ud_data_extract/$', views.uddataextract, name='uddataextract'),
```

The path for `views.users` works fine when the specific user does not have direct reports or when `user.isManager` is `False` in my html page. It's when a user has direct reports that it inserts the links to the direct reports and the page crashes.

**views.py**

```
def users(request, env):
    msg = ''
    searching = (request.method == 'POST') or (request.GET.get('s', None))
    if searching:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            search_text = request.POST.get('search', None)
        else:
            search_text = request.GET.get('s', None)
        if search_text:
            hid = None
            vid = None
            token = None
            person = None
            group = None
            # Figure out what kind of entry this is
            if search_text.isdigit():
                hid = search_text
            elif len(search_text) < 100:
                if '.' in search_text:
                    group = search_text
                else:
                    vid = search_text
            else:
                token = search_text
            # Search by appropriate method
            try:
                person = _get_person(env=env,
                                     hid=hid,
                                     vid=vid,
                                     token=token,
                                     group=group)
            except Exception:
                pass  # throws error when not found
            if isinstance(person, list):
                users, groups = person
                return render_to_response('user_search/user_search.html',
                                          {'users': [dict(u) for u in users],
                                           'groups': groups,
                                           'name': group})
            if person:
                return render_to_response('user_search/user_results.html',
                                          {'user': person.__dict__,
                                           'env': env})
            else:
                msg = 'The user(s) could not be found for the criteria provided.'
    return render_to_response('user_search/user_search.html',
                              {'message': msg})

    def users_staff(request, env, hid):
        manager = _get_person(hid=hid)
        directs = _get_directs(hid=hid)
        emptype = None
        msg = ''  # str(manager) + '|' + str(directs)
        template = 'user_search/user_staff.html'
        if request.GET.get('org', None):
            template = 'user_search/user_org.html'
        if request.GET.get('dldata', None):
            template = 'user_search/user_staff_dldata.html'
            emptype = request.GET.get('dldata').lower()
            if emptype == 'employees':
                emptype = ['Employee']
            elif emptype == 'contractors':
                emptype = ['Contractor']
            else:
                emptype = ['Employee', 'Contractor']
        return render_to_response(template,
                                  {'manager': manager.__dict__,
                                   'users': [dict(d) for d in directs],
                                   'emptype': emptype,
                                   'message': msg})
```

I have tried changing the pathing in the html template to include the parent directory and that didn't work, I also tried removing the `views.*` off the path and that resolves an error saying

```
Reverse for 'users_staff' with arguments '('production', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user_search/user/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/(?P<hid>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Comment: Using `'users_staff'` is correct. Because name of the url is `users_staff`. Now the error is occurring because it is not getting `hid` in the template. You need to make sure to pass `user` object which has attribute `hid`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why it would say it can't find ```views.users_staff``` if it's missing an attribute or not passing the ```user``` object. I would think in that case it would give an error stating it's was missing an attribute.

Plus I can see the ```hid``` being passed in the url.